# Get cookies from req with node.js

Tags: node.js, cookies, session-cookies

I have such cookie on the front end:

```
{'cid': '0001'}
```

On my back end I have such route handler:

```
router.get '/:link', scrapeService.run
```

And the service:

```
exports.run = (req, res, next) ->
  {linkId} = req.params
  console.log res.cookies, 'COOKIE--->>>'
```

Last line returns **undefined**
Also I have in MW:

```
app.use cookieParser()
```

Comment: What web server library do you use? What router library do you use?

Comment: request, routes, express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request cookies stored in `req.cookies` according to https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser

You can send cookies to response by `res.cookie('cookieName', value)`

so replacing `res.cookies` with `req.cookies` must work for you

Comment: sure... just found that my coockie parser is used after routes